# How to make guest sessions start with Unity 2D by Default?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-2d, users

My PC does not have enough resources to run two accounts in Unity 3D.

When I open a guest account from an already started session, it uses Unity 3D by default. How do I change that?

Answer (score 3):

It is an interesting question. I've had a look at this, and it seems to be a bug somewhere. In my opinion, you should've been able to add a file called .dmrc to /etc/guest-session/skel containing

```
[Desktop]
Session=sessionname
```

Where sessionname can be something like "ubuntu", "ubuntu-2d", "gnome", etc. But this doesn't work no matter what I've tried. There are several bug reports about similar issues, so this will be looked into.

I did come up with a solution for you, however, but it's really hacky and just hides the problem without fixing it. But it does work. Open a terminal and paste the following commands: (Make sure you get the whole commands, otherwise you'll get into trouble)

```
sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-3d.session
sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-2d.session /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session
```

This just swaps the two sessions, so any user who has chosen to use Unity and not Unity 2D will also be logged in with Unity 2D until he/she chooses differently again. This also means that any new users you create will default to using Unity 2D.

Comment: I agree with you that works, but doesn't solve the problem just hides it. Is this already reported as a bug on launchpad?

Comment: It doesn't look like that particular bug has been reported, although I did find some similar reports. Will you report it?

Comment: well i have not a launchpad account and I don't know how to report a bogg Could you do it?